# Load config/parameters yml based on value in symfony2 controller

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to create this:

```
MyBundle/resources/config/settings/site1.yml
MyBundle/resources/config/settings/site2.yml
MyBundle/resources/config/settings/site3.yml
```

Where inside each one i could have:

```
parameterWidth: 230
parameterHeight: 145
```

Could someone help me with creating extension so i could use those values in my controller based on variable (1,2,3) to load specific config?

I have already read documentation ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html ) about extensions but none of them is helping me.

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'll store your site number in the *site* parameter, in your bundle's DependencyInjection extension you can do the following:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $file = 'default.yml';
    if ($container->hasParameter('site')) {
        $file = 'site'.$container->getParameter('site');
    }

    $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/settings'));
    $loader->load($file);
}
```

Comment: This did help me. Thank you. I did some modifications to your version but its definitely the right direction